# Visual Studio 2017 unable to download installation files

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I get this error on installing Visual Studio 2017:

> Unable to download installation files. Check your internet connection and try again.

I'm committed to make an online install, I don't have the option to do
an offline install.

I tried using `gpedit.msc` as  described in this [link](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/746735/visual-studio-2017-unable-to-download-installation.html), and
I installed the needed certificates, and still have the same problem.

Can anybody advise what else I can check/fix to make the online install?

Tried Harry's suggestion with same bad result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYDjU.png)

Comment: Try to use the `--noweb` option to prevent the installer from downloading files. Disable any anti-virus.

Comment: Tx HarryMc, tried  noweb option, same result, no antivirus on my machine. I thin I got lost with those Certificates, never worked with them. I updated pics

Comment: I don't see any W certificates, like in one of pic

Comment: @Mich28 - What exactly are "W Certificates"?  You shouldn't have to install any additional certificates to install VS2017.

Comment: Tx RamH, that was just my guess, I on on fresh updated W10, no antivirus, didn't mess with any Certificates. I'm new to them, just mentioned them b'z all google results mentioned Certificates..

Comment: And I don't have problem with installing any other apps, e.g. I did install SSMS OK.

Comment: How have you installed and which certificates? Did you right-click the exe/msi > Properties > Digital Signatures, select the signature > Details > View certificate > Install certificate? Is the system service "CNG key isolation" running?

Comment: Tx Harry, Yes I tried install Cert, didn't see CNG or Lsass running.  I gave up for now. Tx all